# Google Maps Api Nearby Search - Why does google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE return fewer results?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just as the title states. I have tried `google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE` (default) and setting the radius to 50000 and am returned 20 results. But when I try the exact same search, minus the radius as according to the documentation, and using `google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE` I am only returned 3 results in a short radius of my locations. Can someone explain why this happens and how to get a nearby search by distance with full results. Maybe I am just doing something wrong. Thanks.

The code bellow returns 20 results using `google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE`

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var location = {lat: 43.139387, lng: -80.264425};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: location,
    zoom: 9
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: location,
    radius: 50000,
    types: ['police'],
    // rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code bellow returns only 3 results when using `google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE`

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var location = {lat: 43.139387, lng: -80.264425};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: location,
    zoom: 9
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: location,
    // radius: 50000,
    types: ['police'],
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 8896: Bug: Sort By Distance returns fewer number of results.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8896) (not that it provides much information...)

Comment: Related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 6914: Bug: Nearby Search with rankby=distance doesn't return enough results](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6914)

Answer (score 0):

The `radius` attribute for the PROMINENCE code may have an effect on the search result. And based on the [Places documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), it can be affected by Google's index, global popularity, etc.

For DISTANCE, the optional attributes such as `keyword`, `name`, and `types` are now required.

Hope this clarifies some points regarding your issue.

Comment: It turns out its a bug with google maps api. It's been report last year already just not fixed yet. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6914 So i will have to do a work around.

Comment: Well, that's good to hear! Hopefully a fix will be released for that issue soon.